# How to pass value to placeholder to textInput in redux-form?

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, redux-form, react-props

So I'm creating a login form with two fields, username & password respectively; and I would like to pass placeholder to each of these Field. however, no matter what I try, the placeholder is not shown.

## Code

```js
const submit = values => {
  console.log('submitting form', values)
};

const renderInput = ({ input: { onChange, ...restInput } }) => {
  return <TextInput style = { styles.input } onChangeText = { onChange } { ...restInput }/>
};

const LoginForm = props => { const { handleSubmit } = props;
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View>
        <Field name="email"    placeholder="Email"    component={renderInput} />
        <Field name="password" placeholder="Password" component={renderInput} />
      </View>

      <View>
        <View style={styles.loginBtnContainer}>
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={handleSubmit(submit)}>
            <Text style={{fontSize: 30, color: '#17a2e0'}}>Login</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  )
}

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'test'
})(LoginForm)
```

As you can see, the two fields with `name` email & password respectively are not present in TextInput in renderInput function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your component `renderInput` in its `props` you will have available the ones applied to the component `Field`. As [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#placeholder) states, you just have to apply the attribute `placeholder` in the `TextInput` component to get placeholder rendered.

```
const renderInput = ({ placeholder, input: { onChange, ...restInput } }) => {
    return <TextInput placeholder={placeholder} style = { styles.input } onChangeText = { onChange } { ...restInput }/>
};
```

Comment: Daz, thank you for your comment, I had been trying that for hours before raising the question here, but now it works. I don't know what happened. But yh now it works.